# Unlocking files to write to them in Ruby on windows

Tags: ruby, windows, file-permissions

I'm trying to use something like the following to open and write to a locked file:

```
File.open("my_file.feature", "w") do |file|
  file.flock File::LOCK_UN
  ...
end
```

I get the following error:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - my_file.feature
```

How do you handle locked files in Ruby with Windows?

Comment: I think this is because `flock` is not functional in the Windows environment, so you can't use it. A lot of POSIX features are completely absent from the Windows system API.

Comment: @tadman: Then `NotImplementedError` would've been raised. [Windows can lock files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I know Windows can lock files, but the API it uses is completely different from the POSIX one. Does `flock` implement using that on the Windows platform? The [`flock`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) function is what that Ruby method wraps around. You should note that in the documentation it's clearly specified as [not available on all platforms](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-i-flock).